# Evaluation criteria for NIST finalist candidates

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, nist, kem

I have seen several recent papers mention that side-channel resistance and countermeasure will be a major evaluation criterion for the NIST finalist candidates. However, I don't find any reference to this. Has NIST officially declared this criterion? I can find this [document](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/post-quantum-cryptography/documents/round-3/guidelines-for-sumbitting-tweaks-third-round.pdf) which has mentioned only about performance but nothing about side-channels.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The keyword is call.

Answer (score 1):

In the [initial call for submissions](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Post-Quantum-Cryptography/documents/call-for-proposals-final-dec-2016.pdf) in section 4.A.6 *Additional Security Properties*, they do state:

> Another case where security and performance interact is resistance to side-channel attacks. Schemes that can be made resistant to side-channel attack at minimal cost are more desirable than those whose performance is severely hampered by any attempt to resist side-channel attacks. We further note that optimized implementations that address side-channel attacks (e.g., constant-time implementations) are more meaningful than those which do not.

Although the language does not suggest that this is a major criterion, it is nevertheless at least a desideratum.

They also state in their [report on the outcome of the second round](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/ir/2020/NIST.IR.8309.pdf) (Section 4 *Conclusion*)

> NIST hopes that with only seven finalists and eight alternate candidates, the public review period will include more work on side-channel resistant implementations, performance data in internet protocols, and performance data for hardware implementations in addition to more rigorous cryptanalytical study.

which could be regarded as increasing the emphasis.